# Flutter RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded. error with 134 pixel?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is my code in android studio(Windows system)

How to solve this, I have used singlechildscrollview but getting RenderFlex children have non-zero

```
error......?
```

also I have wrapped with widget but same issue........?

Below is my code:

```
     void main() {
              runApp(MyApp());
            }
            class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
              // This widget is the root of your application.
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return MaterialApp(
                  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                  theme: ThemeData(
                    fontFamily: 'ubuntu',
                  ),
                  home: MyHomePage(),
                  routes: {
                    '/MainPage' : (context)=>MainPage(),
                  },
                );
              }
            }
            class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
              @override
              _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
            }
            
            class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
                  backgroundColor: purple,
                  body: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: 100,
                          height: 50,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage('asset/image/logo.png')
                              )
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 30,),
                        Text("Clean Home\nClean Life", style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 40,
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900
                        ),textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                        SizedBox(height: 30,),
                        Text("Book Cleans At The Comfort \nOf Your Home", style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            
                        ), textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                        SizedBox(height: 60,),
                        Container(
                          height: 350,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: AssetImage('asset/image/splash.png'),
                                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                              )
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Container(),
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: openMainPage,
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 30),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
                                    color: Colors.white
                                ),
                                child: Text('Continue..', style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                    color: purple
                                ),),
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            
              void openMainPage()
              {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/MainPage');
              }
            }
........
```

Answer (score 0):

To make content scrollable it must overflow the viewport height. As you use `Expanded` before `Row` so your `Column` is expanded to the maximum height and there is nothing to scroll. If you remove `Expanded` from `Container` and set for thos `Container` height (eg.500.0) than your content will overflow the view port and become scrollable.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'ubuntu',
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
      // routes: {
      //   '/MainPage' : (context)=>MainPage(),
      // },
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 50,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-3VnKmSv5FXg/XCc1YFehs-I/AAAAAAAAPt4/zxnpIVoYSvQFGtIVeNqTILDsCaIg8Ql-wCLcBGAs/s1600/Mirillis%2B-%2BSplash%2BPremium%2BFull%2Bversion.png'))),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Text(
              "Clean Home\nClean Life",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 40,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30,
            ),
            Text(
              "Book Cleans At The Comfort \nOf Your Home",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 18,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 60,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 350,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage(
                          'https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-3VnKmSv5FXg/XCc1YFehs-I/AAAAAAAAPt4/zxnpIVoYSvQFGtIVeNqTILDsCaIg8Ql-wCLcBGAs/s1600/Mirillis%2B-%2BSplash%2BPremium%2BFull%2Bversion.png'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
            ),
            //! Comment this
            // Expanded(
            //   child: Container(),
            // ),
            //! Add height here
            Container(
              height: 500,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: openMainPage,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 60, vertical: 30),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.only(topLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
                        color: Colors.white),
                    child: Text(
                      'Continue..',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 17,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          color: Colors.purple),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void openMainPage() {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/MainPage');
  }
}
```

P.S. I replaced `AssetImage` with `NetworkImage` because I have no your images.